# Summing range of times without counting overlaps twice

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, datetime, mariadb

For a given user ID "1" and a given day 2018-01-02, I want to calculate the total amount of hours logged, where overlaps can exist.

Calculating for this subset:

```
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
| uid | time_start          | time_end            |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
|   1 | 2018-01-02 04:00:00 | 2018-01-02 04:30:00 |
|   1 | 2018-01-02 04:25:00 | 2018-01-02 04:35:00 |
|   1 | 2018-01-02 04:55:00 | 2018-01-02 05:15:00 |
+-----+---------------------+---------------------+
```

The result time should be: **00:55**.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: MariaDB 10.3 - I'll update the question :)

Comment: Surely the result should be `0:55 (0:30 + 0:05 + 0:20)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB 10.3 has window functions and CTE's so you can use those to generate your results. The CTE removes the overlaps from the session times by comparing the current `time_start` with the maximum previous `time_end` for that day and taking the maximum (greatest) value of them and then the query simply `SUM`s each session time, grouping by user id and date. Note that if one session is completely overlapped by another, the CTE sets both `start` and `end` times to the `end` time of the overlapping session, resulting in an effective session length of 0. I've expanded my demo to include such a scenario, as well as multiple overlapping sessions:

```
WITH sessions AS 
    (SELECT uid,
            GREATEST(time_start, COALESCE(MAX(time_end) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(time_start) ORDER BY time_start ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND 1 PRECEDING), '2000-01-01')) AS start,
            MAX(time_end) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(time_start) ORDER BY time_start ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING)  AS end
            FROM sessions)
SELECT uid, DATE(start) AS `date`, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TO_SECONDS(end) - TO_SECONDS(start))) AS totaltime
FROM sessions
GROUP BY uid, `date`
```

Output:

```
uid     date        totaltime
1       2018-01-02  00:55:00
1       2018-01-03  01:00:00
1       2018-01-04  01:15:00
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=f1d9c2c6f9548dea3e14726edb0f5cd8)

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant! Runs very quickly (my previous "almost-working" solution was taking forever since upgrade to MariaDB 10.3) and the results seem to be accurate! :) Thank you very much.

Comment: @Nuno no worries. This was a really interesting problem and I've learnt a bit more about window functions on the way through.

Answer (score 0):

This is a form of gaps-and-islands problem.  It is a real pain in MySQL but I think you can do it with variables.

The idea is to iterate through the records and note when a new start is *not* overlapping with the previous "island".  It becomes the start of the next island.  You can then aggregate and get the duration of each island:

```
select island_start,
       (to_seconds(max(time_start)) - to_seconds(min(time_end))) as num_seconds
from (select t.*,
             (@ts := if(time_start <= @te,
                        if(@te := greatest(@te, time_end), @ts, @ts),  -- no change on the start
                        if(@te := time_end, time_start, time_start)
                       )
             ) as island_start
      from (select t.*
            from t
            order by time_start
           ) t cross join
           (select @ts := -1, @te := -1) params
     ) t
group by island_start;
```

You can use this as a subquery to add up the differences.

Answer (score 0):

This was a great and enjoyable exercise.

So, the trick here is the following:

1. The person logged in again before logging out from his last session and ended the session after his first session; or
2. The person logged in again before logging out from his last session and ended the session before ending his first session

So, the trick to solve it is just to assign the new session a beginning time a time equal to the ending time of his previous session. In this case, you will have each session as a row and you will be able to calculate time differences. Ok, let's simulate examples of this
:

```
  create table #temp (userId int, timeComienza datetime, timeTermina dateTime )

-- exemplo de overlap
  insert into #temp values (1, '20180102 16:00', '20180102 16:30')
  insert into #temp values (1, '20180102 16:25', '20180102 16:35')
  insert into #temp values (1, '20180102 16:55', '20180102 17:15')
-- ejemplo de no overlap
  insert into #temp values (2, '20180102 16:00', '20180102 16:30')
  insert into #temp values (2, '20180102 16:35', '20180102 16:50')
  insert into #temp values (2, '20180102 16:40', '20180102 16:45')


userId  timeComienza    timeTermina
1   2018-01-02 16:00:00.000 2018-01-02 16:30:00.000
1   2018-01-02 16:25:00.000 2018-01-02 16:35:00.000
1   2018-01-02 16:55:00.000 2018-01-02 17:15:00.000
2   2018-01-02 16:00:00.000 2018-01-02 16:30:00.000
2   2018-01-02 16:35:00.000 2018-01-02 16:50:00.000
2   2018-01-02 16:40:00.000 2018-01-02 16:45:00.000
```

As you can see user 1 suffers from logging in his second session before ending his first session and user 2 suffers from almost the same problem in his third session except that his third session ended before ending his 2nd session (a total overlap and eclipse of his second session).

The first thing we need to do, is to provide an order of these session with the use of order by.

```
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by userId order by timeComienza) as unOrden 
into #temp2 
from #temp 

userId  timeComienza    timeTermina         unOrden
1   2018-01-02 16:00:00.000 2018-01-02 16:30:00.000 1
1   2018-01-02 16:25:00.000 2018-01-02 16:35:00.000 2
1   2018-01-02 16:55:00.000 2018-01-02 17:15:00.000 3
2   2018-01-02 16:00:00.000 2018-01-02 16:30:00.000 1
2   2018-01-02 16:35:00.000 2018-01-02 16:50:00.000 2
2   2018-01-02 16:40:00.000 2018-01-02 16:45:00.000 3
```

Now, it would be a 100 times easier to work with our iterations.
Let's create an empty table with the same structure as table #2 to be our table to insert our analysis.

```
select * 
into #tablaInsertar
from #temp2

delete from #tablaInsertar
```

And finally, here is the core of our analysis :)

```
-- variable to iterate users
declare @x int = 1 , @usuarios int = 1, @usuariosMax int
--num dif de usuarios:
select @usuariosMax = count(distinct(userId)) from #temp2 


while(@usuarios <= @usuariosMax)
begin

/*trabajando cada usuario*/
    /*Primero necesitamos saber la longitud de cada Usuario*/
    declare @trabajaUsuario int = 1, @longUsuario int

    --obtiene longitud usuario
    select @longUsuario = count(1) from #temp
    where userId = @usuarios

    while(@trabajaUsuario <= @longUsuario)
    begin 

        if(@trabajaUsuario = 1)
        begin 

            insert into #tablaInsertar
            select 
                *
            from #temp2
            where userId = @usuarios and unOrden = @trabajaUsuario

        end 

        else -- dado que no sea la primera fila
        -- comparando horas
        begin 
                declare @horaInicioEstePeriodo dateTime, @horaTerminaAnterior dateTime
                select @horaInicioEstePeriodo = #temp2.timeComienza from #temp2 where userId = @usuarios and unOrden = @trabajaUsuario
                select @horaTerminaAnterior = #temp2.timeTermina from #temp2 where userId = @usuarios and unOrden = @trabajaUsuario - 1

                if(@horaInicioEstePeriodo < @horaTerminaAnterior) -- las modificaciones dado que el periodo inicio sea menro a la hora anterior
                begin 

                    insert into #tablaInsertar
                    select 
                        t2.userId
                        , t1.timeTermina as tiempoComienzaActualizado
                        , t2.timeTermina
                        , t2.unOrden
                    from 
                        (
                            select 
                                #temp2.userId
                                ,#temp2.timeComienza
                                , #temp2.timeTermina
                                , #temp2.unOrden
                            from #temp2
                            where userId = @usuarios and unOrden = @trabajaUsuario - 1
                        )t1
                        join
                        (
                            select 
                                #temp2.userId
                                --, as tiempoComienzaActualizado --#temp2.timeComienza
                                , #temp2.timeTermina
                                , #temp2.unOrden
                            from #temp2
                            where userId = @usuarios and unOrden = @trabajaUsuario
                        ) t2 on t1.userId = t2.userId and t1.unOrden + 1 = t2.unOrden
                end 

                else -- dado que el periodo inicia sea mayor o igual a la hora anterior
                begin 

                    insert into #tablaInsertar
                    select 
                        *
                    from #temp2
                    where userId = @usuarios and unOrden = @trabajaUsuario
                end 

        end 

    select @trabajaUsuario += 1
    end

select @usuarios += 1
end
```

Let's take a look at our new table :)

```
select *, DATEDIFF(s,timeComienza,timeTermina) timeInSeconds
from #tablaInsertar

userId  timeComienza    timeTermina unOrden timeInSeconds
1   2018-01-02 16:00:00.000 2018-01-02 16:30:00.000 1   1800
1   2018-01-02 16:30:00.000 2018-01-02 16:35:00.000 2   300
1   2018-01-02 16:55:00.000 2018-01-02 17:15:00.000 3   1200
2   2018-01-02 16:00:00.000 2018-01-02 16:30:00.000 1   1800
2   2018-01-02 16:35:00.000 2018-01-02 16:50:00.000 2   900
2   2018-01-02 16:50:00.000 2018-01-02 16:45:00.000 3   -300
```

As we can see, user 1 session 2 is now properly reflecting his mere 300 seconds that he really worked (5 minutes). And for user 2 session 3 problem we have a negative number, and the reason is because he is taking time from his session 2. So, all we need to do is to sum positive values only to know the real time logged by each user, like so:

```
select 
    t1.userId,
    sum(case when timeInSeconds > 0 then timeInSeconds else 0 end) totalTimeLogged
from 
(
    select *, DATEDIFF(s,timeComienza,timeTermina) timeInSeconds
    from #tablaInsertar
) t1
group by t1.userId
```

Final Result:

```
userId  totalTimeLogged
1           3300
2           2700
```