# Compare values with other rows in the same table and return Aggregated result

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to calculate total experience of a user. Points to note:

- Every experience is a row,
- A row will have *timePeriodStart*, *timePeriodEnd*, *currentlyWorking*.

My current query for getting total experience in days.

```
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(DAY, EX.TimePeriodStart,
                                           CASE
                                               WHEN EX.TimePeriodEnd IS NULL
                                               THEN GETUTCDATE()
                                               ELSE EX.TimePeriodEnd
                                           END)) AS 'TotalExpInDays', 
                    EX.UserPersonalDetailsId
             FROM Experience EX
             GROUP BY EX.UserPersonalDetailsId
```

But a user can do more than one job for a specific time period. So, what I have decided is to subtract the common number days from the total time.

My query to calculate common days:

```
SELECT SUM(CASE
           WHEN EX.TimePeriodStart BETWEEN EX2.TimePeriodStart AND EX2.TimePeriodEnd
           THEN DATEDIFF(DAY, EX.TimePeriodStart,
                                 CASE
                                     WHEN EX2.TimePeriodEnd IS NULL
                                     THEN GETUTCDATE()
                                     ELSE EX2.TimePeriodEnd
                                 END)
           ELSE 0
       END) AS 'DaysToSub', 
   EX.UserPersonalDetailsId
FROM Experience EX
     LEFT JOIN Experience EX2 ON EX2.UserPersonalDetailsId = EX.UserPersonalDetailsId
                                 AND EX2.ExperienceId != EX.ExperienceId
WHERE EX.UserPersonalDetailsId = UserPersonalDetailsId -- userId-int
GROUP BY EX.UserPersonalDetailsId
```

Here's a [link](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/5dWTA8jK95HRUKiL2DQe3Z/4) to the fiddle (Slightly modified for MySQL)

Problem with this query: It gives proper value if there's two overlapping dates but if there's more than 2 overlapping rows its showing duplicate data (which is logical as it's comparing the same date with more than 1 row). How do I avoid this?

The problem felt complicated to write down here, I tried to make it as easy possible. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Example Input:

> ```
> Id | startdate           | enddate             | UserId
> -: | :------------------ | :------------------ | -----:
>  1 | 01/03/2018 00:00:00 | 31/03/2018 00:00:00 |      1
>  4 | 18/04/2019 00:00:00 | 15/05/2019 00:00:00 |      1
>  2 | 15/03/2018 00:00:00 | 15/04/2018 00:00:00 |      1
>  3 | 17/04/2018 00:00:00 | 15/04/2019 00:00:00 |      1
> ```

Desired Output:

> ```
> Id | startdate           | enddate             | UserId
> -: | :------------------ | :------------------ | -----:
>  1 | 01/03/2018 00:00:00 | 31/03/2018 00:00:00 |      1
>  4 | 18/04/2019 00:00:00 | 15/05/2019 00:00:00 |      1
>  2 | 31/03/2018 00:00:00 | 15/04/2018 00:00:00 |      1
>  3 | 17/04/2018 00:00:00 | 18/04/2019 00:00:00 |      1
> ```

The problem is quite comlicated for me. Can't seem to get my around it!

Comment: I've removed those conflicting dbms tags. Add one of them back, the one for the dbms actually used.

Comment: Okay, but I added them as the problem is not specific to any dbms. Anyone with good knowledge on any dbms can help me out.

Comment: If you're using MySQL, I'd recommend adding the <mysql> tag. (When it comes to date/time many products have their own, non-portable functions.)

Comment: If you are actually using SQL Server, you should create a fiddle for SQL Server, e.g. here: https://dbfiddle.uk/

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54545433/summing-range-of-times-without-counting-overlaps-twice) might be useful

Comment: @Nick, Thanks for the link. Looks like it'll work.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Edited to add the desired output.